# Difficulty with using Flask to host static and templates files

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I want to host 3 files in `app.py` using the Flask framework. Here is what it looks like.

```
Project
    ├── templates
    │   └── index.html
    ├── static
    │   ├── index.js
    │   └── style.css
    └── app.py
```

How do I host these files in `app.py` using the Flask framework? Here is my attempt at it, but it is giving me an error that the site can't be reached when I run the `app.py` server file.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index_html():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/index.js')
def index_js():
    return render_template('index.js')

@app.route('/style.css')
def style_css():
    return render_template('style.css')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is also what that is included in my `index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
```

One more thing, when I inspect the page and go to sources, none of my `index.js`, `style.css`, and `index.html` files are there. This basically means that app.py can't find none of those files that are located in my templates and static folder.

Comment: I don't understand why you have done this. JS and CSS are not templates, they are static files.

Comment: Remove the routes for your static files. Those are likely interfering with what Flask would otherwise do.

Answer (score 0):

They are already hosted you can acces them from an html file let's say:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="../static/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index_html():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```